# How to pass same instance of object in two function in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, object

I need to send same instance of object of a class in two function (Main function and thread function)

The program is something like this

```
Class ABC
{
}obj(32);

void F1()
{
   obj.test;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
     obj.test1;
    _beginthread(F1,0,(void*)number);
}
```

In the above sample, I have created class ABC and declared its object as obj(32). I call this object in Main function . In Main function , function 'F1' is called using thread and same object 'obj' is called in function 'F1'.

The code works well when the object of class ABC is created as shown above. My problem is the value that is passed in the object ('32') is to be read from the file.

If I read the file and create object separately in Main function and function 'F1' then , function 'F1' is not executed.

How to create same instance of object for Main function and function 'F1' with value passed in the object taken from the file.

The code used to read from file is

```
FILE *fileread;
int character;
fileread=fopen("C:/file.txt", "r");
if (fileread==NULL) 
{ 
return 1; // exit with failure 
}
int n,number;
while((fscanf(fileread, "%d",&n))==1)
{
number=n;
}
fclose(fileread);
```

Now, the object created should be sth like `obj(number)`

This same instance of `ABC obj(number)` is to be defined in both Main function and function 'F1'.

//////////////////Updated one//////////////////////////////////////////////

My class is something like this

```
Class ABC
{
public:
    DWORD *IdG;

   ABC(int number)
   { 
       IdG = new DWORD[number];
   }
}
```

Then i defined typedef so that i can send two parameter in beginthread

```
typedef struct ST{ 
    int num; 
    CMinimalServer* srv1;
}thestruct;
```

My function is something like this

```
void F1(thestruct* st)
```

And the main function is

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    thestruct st;
    st.num =32;
    st.srv1; // problem is here how to specify class constructor as srv1(32).

    //beginthread part is modified as below
    _beginthread((void(*)(void*))ModbusReadWrite,0,(void*)&st);
```

I need to create class object as `ABC srv1(32)`

Comment: Make the function parameter `F1(ABC* obj)` and pass a pointer to it as argument in `_beginthread` as `_beginthread(F1,0,(void*)obj);`.

Comment: Is it important for you to use the (Win-OS) lowlevel threading facilities? Otherwise I'd recommend to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) et.al.

Comment: @Etherealone thank you for your comment , i cannot send obj as void , so i created struct and i have updated the changed madein above post. can you please help me .

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i have to use low level threading . I have updated the post . can you please have a look in it

Comment: @Jenifer _'i cannot send obj as void'_ You have to pass the address to the thread function as `void*` and cast it back to the objects address type in the thread function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a constructor for the struct:

```
typedef struct ST {
    int num;
    CMinimalServer* srv1;
    explicit ST(int num);
} thestruct; 

ST::ST(int _num) : num(_num), srv1(new ABC(_num))
{
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
     thestruct st(32);
     // here:
     // st.num == 32
     // st.srv1 points to ABC(32)
```

Comment: thank you for the response. How to define the object of the struct in the main function when we define constructor for the struct. Previously we defined as "thestruct st; st.num =32; st.srv1"

Comment: I have unfolded the answer a bit. Any more details?